How to pass a model to component to retrieve all fields and data?
I wanted to build a component-table which will build a table for any model that is passed and I believe it is gotta be easy but I can't come up with solution.
public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = new $model;
        $this->columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($model);
    }

I used DB to get columns but I'm pretty sure it has to be done through model and I don't know how.

Which version of laravel you are using?

it is 8.83.27. I don't know why, but composer decided to create this, instead of 11.

Because PHP version might be insufficient to install Laravel 11.What error you are getting in above code?

There are no errors, I just can't come up with proper solution. Aren't models used to interact with DB? Then I assume they should be used to get all the columns. I also need to get data from the DB. I am not sure that direct interaction with DB via component is proper and can't find other solution that would give me both columns and data

I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.

Your __constructor() defination is incorrect. You can do this instead.
public function __construct()
{
        $userModel = new User();  
        $this->table = $userModel->getTable();
}

As an example here I am using User model in above code-block.You also need to import User i.e use App\Models\User; to the top of the script.
After you define __constructor(), you can get both column & data from the method() of that Controller in this way.
Then Do this.
public function tableColumnAndData()
{
    $columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->table);

    // Get table data
    $data = DB::table($this->table)->get();

    // Combine columns and data
    $result = [
        'columns' => $columns,
        'data' => $data
    ];

    return response()->json($result);
}

*Import Model-class that you are using in the script i.e use App\Models\Model-Name;.
*Import DB facade to the top of the script i.e use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
Try this,It will work.
